# What do you call a disk drive that is not solid state?

Tags: word-choice, antonyms, technology

I tried searching for things like *opposite of solid-state*, but most of what I've found suggest things like *liquid-state*. I'm pretty sure a drive that is not solid-state contains no liquid to speak of.

Is there a one word antonym for the use of *solid-state* in this context?

Comment: ............old?

Comment: @LarsTech - or "Rust on the Run" ?

Comment: Colloquially I've also heard the term "spindles"

Comment: You mean one that actually has a disk in it?

Comment: Even more obsolete are tape drives, which shows there are more than 2 types of drives.

Comment: i call it paperweight

Comment: Hence the acronyms SSD (solid state drive) and HDD (hard disk drive).

Comment: I thought everyone called them [Winchester drives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_hard_disk_drives).

Comment: In my circle of IT geeks, we call them "spinners."

Comment: Due to the actual meaning of Solid State, mechanical is the only logical antonym. In the context of disk drives though, you're talking SSD and HDD. If they know what solid state means they'll know what HDD means. They won't know "liquid state" and "magnetic drive" would be an unusual term.

Comment: @Zoredache I would've liked to mark your comment as the correct answer. It is succinct, technically correct, and clear enough that anyone with whom I might end up needing to make the distinction between a *solid-state* drive and a *Winchester drive* would either already know it, or chuckle and immediately look it up.

Comment: Liquid state drive? Gaseous state drive? Legacy? :)

Comment: I realize this question is old, but I propose it be edited to show the original intent: was the OP asking about fixed storage (HDD vs. SSD), or was it about all storage devices?

Comment: @MathieuK. hmm, when I asked, I specifically had in mind the notion that there were only two main types of hard disk drives: the kind with spinning platters, and the solid state kind.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

*Solid-state drives* are called *[solid-state](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_state_%28electronics%29)* because there are no moving parts in them. Drives with moving parts are called *hard disk drives*, because they contain *disks* which rotate when the drive is powered on. You could consider this an antonym, but not necessarily. They are simply two different technologies, with many other possible to come.

Comment: Are you suggesting that a *hard disk drive* is never *solid-state*? I'm surprised. Is it the word *drive* that makes it not *solid-state*?

Comment: @kojiro: both are *drives*. One of them is SOLID STATE drive and the other is HARD DISK drive. You could call it a *solid state disk*, but NEVER *solid state hard disk.*

Comment: I'm still surprised. I could see how a solid-state drive needn't have a *disk*, but it is just as, if not more, deserving of the term *hard* as its moving-parts cousin. Do you have a reference?

Comment: @kojiro http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive

Comment: @kojiro: Welcome to the messy front of language being born :)  RiMMER is exactly correct.

Comment: The term "solid state" means "made from transistors and/or integrated circuits". Just because a hard disk is a solid object, as opposed to liquid or gas, I suppose, doesn't make it "solid state". Phrases often have more specific meaning than their constituent parts. I could sit a desktop computer on my lap, but that doesn't make it a "laptop computer"! I could have a friend who is a girl, but that doesn't make her "my girlfriend". Etc.

Comment: @kojiro The reason why it was called a *hard* disk drive, was because the spinning platters inside (disks) were *rigid*. Later, disk mechanisms with removable soft platters were developed, these drives were called *floppy disk drives* and the media were called *floppy disks*. I suppose they used *floppy* instead of *soft* because the disk isn't soft like a marshmallow or pillow, but instead is flexible. I guess the engineers liked the whimsical sound of *floppy* rather than *flexible disk drives* …

Comment: Well, you could argue that the atmosphere inside the drive (providing an air cushion between the head and the platter) is an integral working part of the drive, and so it's _not_ fully "solid state". Today's hard drives cannot operate in a vacuum.

Comment: Floppy and tape drives have moving parts, but are not considered "Hard disk drives." Also, USB/Thumb drives have no moving parts and are considered solid state "storage devices", or as the name implies, "drives".

Comment: @ghoppe either that or the marketers thought `flexible disk drive` wasn't as catchy

Comment: @Jay: Exactly. I have two computers at work: the desktop is on the floor, and the laptop is on the desk.

Comment: Young group. I'm surprised it took this long for someone to explain the "hard" drive part and not mention in the context "floppy".

Comment: @RiMMERΨ, do you mean a SOLID STATE DRIVE?  There's no DISK in the device.

Comment: @Hugo: And, I might add, I recently bought a laptop that had a paper enclosed that included a warning that, because the computer can get hot, you should not put it on your lap! So ... it's a laptop computer, but you can't put it on your lap. (Not to say I actually obey that warning.)

Comment: @Jay - that's why every computer store (online and bricks-and-mortar) call them "notebooks" now...

Comment: I'm a professional app developer. Played with computers since as long as I can remember. Took appart a disk drive when I was 9 years old to see how it works. 

When someone says "hard disk" I would not immediately assume they mean non-solid state.

Comment: HDDs are also sometimes refered to as 'fixed disks' to distinguish them from removable media such as floppy disks. You install them in the PC and leave them there. While solid-state drives are in the same sense 'fixed', they use no disks.

Comment: @surfasb: "Young group" yourself. How come no one mentioned punch cards? USB drives are a passing fad, you know. Punch cards are coming back.

Comment: It makes me sad that SOLID and HARD are not the same thing in this case. :-(

Comment: @Dave: no, the USB drives you're talking about are flash drives, not SSDs. SSD is usually a term reserved for fixed (non-removable) storage, although there's no reason, to my knowledge, why you couldn't use an SSD in an external USB enclosure. I realize that the technology inside a flash drive and an SSD may be similar or identical, but they have different uses and different connectors, and have, for better or for worse, different names.

Answer (score 72):

The word you are looking for is "magnetic" or "mechanical" (i.e. a mechanical disk drive).

The word "disk drive" has become very ubiquitous and a layman is likely to apply the term to other storage technologies. So, while *technically* you would be correct in saying that a disk drive is something that is not (technically) "solid-state", the term could easily be confused.

This is an English/communication question; not a technical one. The only way to guarantee *understanding* is to properly describe the specific technology you are referring to — mechanical disk drive, platter-based disk drive, old-style noisy rotating spinny magnetic planar disks with crashing heads inducing much rage systems — don't get *too* caught up in the *technical* accuracy when communication and understanding are important.

Comment: I see "magnetic" used almost as frequently as "mechanical", and in aggregate "spinning", "rotating", etc aren't far behind.  All are equally over-broad.  As Sean Vikoren pointed out evolution is messy; it might be a few years before this question can be revisited and given a definitive answer.

Comment: @DanNeely: I +1'd you, but actually I see "magnetic" more often.

Comment: Answer updated to include "magnetic."

Comment: I'd prefer "Electro-Mechanical Magnetic Storage" as the catch all, but this could also refer to tape.

Comment: This is the most correct answer. Although typically they are called "hard disk drive" to differentiate between solid-state and magnetic.

Comment: "Magnetic" is the most accurate definition. +1'd.

Comment: "Hard" was originally to differentiate from "floppy", and is thus more specific than "magnetic".  "Hard disk drive" is much more commonly used than "magnetic disk drive" - about 3:1, according to google.

Answer (score 25):

I'd quibble with some of Rimmer's definitions, but his point is essentially correct.

I believe the real definition of *solid state* is something more like "made with transistors and/or integrated circuits". An old vacuum tube memory unit has no moving parts, either, but wouldn't be called *solid state*. Core memory had no moving parts, etc. (I don't mean to be critical; I'm sure someone could quibble with my definitions too. Just trying to clarify.)

*Hard disk* refers to a technology where data is stored on spinning, rigid disks. We call it *hard* to distinguish it from *floppy disk*, where the disks are flexible, and *disk* to distinguish it from drum storage, where data was stored on the outside of a cylindrical device, i.e. a device that was drum-shaped. (Drum drives have been obsolete for a long time and floppy disks are just about gone, I think.)

A CD is technically a disk that is hard, but we don't call it a *hard disk* because the technology is quite different and we need to distinguish.

Yes, by definition a hard disk drive is not solid state, just like by definition a cathode-ray tube is not a liquid crystal display, etc. I suppose you could make a disk-shaped solid state memory device, but we wouldn't call it a hard disk drive except as a joke.

Personally I think calling a solid state memory unit a *drive* is a misnomer, as I understand the word *drive* to refer to a device with a motor that spins something. But solid-state *drives* have picked up that name by analogy, I think; they're like a hard disk drive except that they're solid state.

And to ditto Rimmer, they're not really opposites; they are two of many existing and many more possible technologies. I've mentioned seven in this post: core memory, vacuum tubes, drums, hard disks, floppy disks, solid state, and CD. I'm sure in the future we'll see other technologies.

Comment: I find both these posts rather interesting, as I've always called them "solid-state hard disks", omitting the "drive" entirely - but also wrong because there is no disk in them!

Comment: Prior to drum storage there was liquid storage. To temporarily store some bits of data there were liquid mercury tanks. The bits were encoded as waves that went down the tank and came back again. So there was liquid-state storage.   But I agree with your definition of solid state from electronics. As technology progressed more devices (music players, controller systems, car computers, medical devices) progressed to solid state technology and became more reliable.  An antonym of solid state in the electronics world (and not the hard disk world)  might be analog.

Comment: That definition isn't entirely correct. Yes, Transistors are solid-state, but that doesn't mean everything else isn't. ie. a resistor network is solid-state. Example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistor_ladder

Comment: Agree that nothing is "driven" in a SSD so the name doesn't fit. FYI though, vacuum tubes contain a moving electron gas, and some tenuous internal gas as well (non-ideal vacuum or even on purpose to improve emission), so they are not solid state.

Comment: Wuser606723: Good point. See, I said some could quibble with my definition, too.

Comment: @potatoswatter: Hmm, solid state devices have moving electrons. I don't think moving electron streams "count" as a moving part.

Comment: @Jay: Although in some ways the moving, bound electrons in silicon can be modeled as a gas, they are still part of the solid semiconductor and not an actual separate gas as in a tube. The point not only that they are moving, but that they are in a non-solid state.

Comment: I'm surprised that the list of seven technologies didn't include magnetic bubble (a.k.a. domain propogation) memory.  It is a magnetic analog of semiconductor storage in that it uses no mechanical motion like drum, disk, tape, or magstripe, so "magnetic storage" doesn't distinguish between moving and stationary media.

Comment: @Dave: I don't claim my list was all-inclusive, just illustrative. And there's a very good reason why I excluded magnetic bubble memory from my list: I never heard of it.

Answer (score 12):

The typical acronyms and phrases are `HDD` for `Hard Disk Drive` and `SSD` for `Solid State Drive`.

The generic "parent" term is `DD` for [`Disk Drive`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_storage).

Adding to this list is `FDD` for `Floppy Disk Drive` (remember those?), `ODD` for [`Optical Disk Drive`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_disc_drive) (more common terms are CD, DVD & Blu-ray Drives though), [`Tape Drive`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tape_drive) and [`USB Flash Drive`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_flash_drive).

To answer your question though, **there really is no opposite term, since hard disks aren't binary in their nature** (yes pun intended)

Comment: I wonder if UFD has ever been used for USB Flash Drives...

Comment: Technically, an USB Flash drive **is** a solid state drive. There is no difference except the package shape, connection method and capacity

Comment: The generic term is *data storage device*, perhaps omitting *data* or *device*. It should not include *disk*.

Comment: @Potatoswatter I agree with you, however `Disk Drive` (`DD`) is the common usage.

Comment: @Izkata: yes. It's not common, though.

Answer (score 8):

Solid-state does not really have an opposite when it comes to this tech. Solid-state in this case refers to the quality of the hard drive; that it does not have moving parts and its internal memory storage is (simply) a solid, non-moving material. A standard hard drive has plates (disks) and arms that move and is, or at least was, called a "hard disk drive".

Comment: Fixed *it's* to *its*, which make my eyes bleed when used incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks for the fix, I often fat-finger that one when I'm typing quickly. Sorry that I made your eyes bleed.

Comment: Solid-state refers to the [electronics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_(electronics)) that make up the storage mechanism.

Comment: It does have an antonym; mechanical.

Comment: @RiMMER - It's the most bs english rule though.... I always write it that way and go back and correct it.

Answer (score 7):

The headline question, *What do you call a disk drive that is not solid state?*, actually reveals the answer, and also the confusion.  The storage device that a *solid-state drive* (SSD) replaces is called a *disk drive*.

The confusion comes because, on the time scale of language evolution, the technology is new and the wording hasn't completely settled down.  The original name for a disk drive was *magnetic disk drive* (which was equipment that rotated a *magnetic disk*), but because essentially all disks in the computer context were magnetic, the *magnetic* was dropped.  When consumer PCs appeared, they first used only *floppy disks* (so called because the magnetic disks were flexible instead of the conventional rigid, or hard, disks).  Then consumer PCs got higher-performing *hard disk drives*, which were usually called *hard drives* or *hard disks* to distinguish them from the earlier consumer *disk drives* which were used for floppies.

When the flash-memory-based replacements for hard disk drives appeared, they came to be called *solid-state drives*, which showed their function as similar to that of a disk *drive*, and their distinct nature, *solid-state*.  There is no disk inside a solid-state drive, just integrated circuits (chips).  The term *solid-state* dates way back to *vacuum tube* (British: *valve*) days, before transistors or chips.  When invented, transistors (and similar things, like later chips) were called *solid-state devices* from the physics term *solid* which distinguished them from earlier devices using a vacuum.  So *solid-state* was used for things built out of chips (like *solid-state memory* such as RAM), and so was used for the non-disk hard drive replacement, the solid-state drive.

Exactly what "opposite" means in the context is a little hazy, but it might be reasonable to say in the context of *mass storage drives* there are *solid-state drives* and *disk drives* (which could include optical disk drives as well as hard disk drives).

Comment: Also, solid state devices are not actually drives, since they contain no driven parts, unlike hard disk drives.

Comment: @kit: true, no mechanical thing is driven in an SSD, but electronics use the term _driver_ for circuits that "push" the electrons into other circuits.  They have drivers that drive the flash chips, in a very loose analogy to the motors that drive the disk in a hard drive.  However, the term _drive_ was presumably used to show the functional equivalence to existing drives rather than as a description of the internal nature.

Comment: +1 This is the most complete answer.  The linguistic evolution and baggage is fascinating.

Answer (score 7):

### Spinning Disk

Most non-SSDs could accurately be called a "spinning disk drive".

Comment: I've heard HDDs perjoratively referred to as "spinning rust", due to the ferrous layer that's used to record the bits:
http://etherealmind.com/network-dictionary-spinning-rust/

Answer (score 6):

I know this isn't a long answer like the others, but you might also consider **Magnetic Storage.** Magnetic Disk Drive would work as well.

Comment: Came here to say this. It's not an opposite as such but it's a reference to the technology, as is solid-state.

Comment: So there's solid state, magnetic, and optical. (CD and DVD variants and others are optical, not magnetic).

Answer (score 3):

Hard Disk Drive (HDD) is typically used as the generic for non Solid State Drives (SSD).

Alternative "disk drives" include:

- 5.25" Floppy Disk
- 3.5" Floppy Disk (Floppy)
- Compact Disk (CD)
- Digital Versatile Disk (DVD)

Answer (score 3):

Usually just be specific, rather than looking for an all-encompassing word, but usually it depends on context and *why* you're trying to differentiate.

Since the most common alternatives to solid-state drives are "[hard disk drives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_drive)" and "[floppy disk drives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floppy_disk)", **a common term to refer to non-SSD disks is *"spinning media."***

Comment: but it is also incorrect to call it a solid-state *drive* because nothing is driven :)

Comment: @JamesRyan besides electricity.

Comment: @JamesRyan Of course it is driven, the storage medium in the drive won't read/write itself, will it? In the traditional sense of the term "drive", the memory controller, all other circuitry, and the firmware in SSDs is the drive that allows data stored on the storage medium, which is typically a flash memory, to be accessed. See [short terminology on computer storage](https://superuser.com/a/1832996)

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer to your question is **Non Solid State Drive**

Why? Because Solid state drives are one family and there are others out there: Optical, Magnetic disk and tape drives to name a few. So it would be incorrect to say that Hard Disk drives are the opposite of Solid State drives.

Now if you are meaning to ask for the most common alternatives to Solid State drives, its probably Hard Disk Drives or optical media (cd/dvd/blue ray) which are alternatives to Solid State drives (depending on application)

Answer (score 1):

I use the term *mechanical* or *electro-mechanical drive*.